# How to set a default layout in a theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-titlebar

I'm using a custom titlebar in my app, but everytime I create a new layout I have to call:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/titlebar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="@integer/titlebar_weight"
    layout="@layout/titlebar" />
```

Instead calling this in all the layouts how can I define it in a theme (in other words: define a default layout for the theme)?

My default layout:

[image: Default Layout]

Answer (score 3):

Although the old title bar can be customized a bit via a theme (`windowTitleStyle`, `windowTitleSize`, `windowTitleBackgroundStyle`), you cannot set your own layout. Also the title bar was replaced by the ActionBar in Android 3.0, so that won't help you anyway.

Setting a default layout in a theme is not possible, at least I could not find a way to do it. But you still have several options to reduce repetition when adding your header layout:

- Create a master layout with your header and a ViewStub for your content, then set the inflatedId by code.
- Consider building your screens with fragments and add/remove them programmatically from your master layout.
- Add the header programmatically in a base activity (suggested by user1527136)
- Include it (that is what you are already doing, and it is not that bad imho)

Comment: The options we have to do it are simple too, there's no need to set a default layout, maybe that's why Android doesn't allow that (and perhaps didn't remember to do that either).
I rushed a bit setting this bounty :/
But thank you for the answer, and you deserve it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against creating the actionbar yourself, you can either try:

[Actionbar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) or ActionbarCompat (from the Google samples in your SDK).

Answer (score 0):

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>    
</resources> 



<activity 

    android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" 

</activity>
```

Comment: What I want to know is: "Instead calling this in layouts how can I define it (a custom titlebar) in a theme?". This is how I remove the default titlebar...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be achieved through theming alone. You would need to create an abstract `Activity` that will include your title bar and wrap the content view set by the extended `Activity` classes. Here's an example:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/titleBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/titlebar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Abstract Activity

```
public abstract class TitleBarActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        super.setContentView( R.layout.title_bar_activity );
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView( int layoutResId ) {

        FrameLayout contentFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById( R.id.content );
        contentFrameLayout.removeAllViews();
        getLayoutInflater().inflate( layoutResId, contentFrameLayout );
    }
}
```

This is a very simple implementation, but should give you the general idea of what you need to do. Now for any Activity that extends `TitleBarActivity`, you'll already have the title bar at the top by default. Any customization of the title you want your activities to control, add methods in `TitleBarActivity` to do so.